# Axios 'Network Error' when making call to Square API

Tags: vue.js, axios, square

I'm writing a website using Vue.js that serves as an online store. My client uses Square to manage in-store purchases, so I figured it would be easiest for them if the website gathers certain information from their Square account (like their products, prices, etc.) rather than maintaining a separate copy for the website.

Specifically, I'd like to gather their Square "Catalog" to get the name and price of each item. Per the [API examples](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/catalog-api/retrieve-catalog-objects), I should just be able to make a simple call to `catalogApi.listCatalog()`, but every time I do this, I get a random axios `Network Error`:

> Error: Network Error
> at createError(src\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
> at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:5174/node_modules/.vite/deps/square.js?v=82a3bd3e:2474:18)
>
> config { url: 'https://connect.squareupsandbox.com/vs/catalog/list' ... }
> isAxiosError: true
> ...

Here is the code that runs the request:

```
// In vue component..
export default {
   
    async mounted() {
        var client = new Client({
            accessToken: {MY_ACCESS_TOKEN},
            environment: Environment.Sandbox
        });

        try {
            const response = await client.catalogApi.listCatalog();
            console.log(response.result);
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }

}
```

The error happens immediately upon calling `listCatalog()`. I am using the Square Sandbox for testing this. I have ensured that I'm using the correct access token. Additionally, I'm positive that my sandbox contains items in its catalog.

I've read about other developers running into CORS issues with this, but they usually get a specific CORS error, as opposed to the more elusive "Network Error".

When I visit the url in the `config` section of the request, chrome displays the exact JSON I'm looking for, with no issue.

If someone could help me out with this, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Not sure if it's because I'm not a Square developer but it's not clear what's happening based on the abstraction. Can you reveal what the bit of magical code `client.catalogApi.listCatalog()` actually does? It seems like `new Client` is axios based, but where does it and it's properties/functions come from?  If you could include the details of the request from your browser's dev tools network tab, that would also be helpful.

Comment: that `listCatalog()` method is 3rd party- it's included in the "Square SDK". Its intended purpose is to make an API request that receives the data in the catalog.

Upon looking at chrome's network tab, it looks like I'm getting a 405 error. I'll double check that my sandbox is setup correctly to allow GET requests of this nature.

Comment: You need to provide more detail. For starters, get more information out of the error object. Something like this should help... `console.error(e.response?.status, e.response?.data, e.toJSON?.())`. You can also simply look in your dev-tools _Network_ panel and inspect the request and response directly. [Edit] your question to include these debugging details once you have them

Comment: Also, if you literally have `{MY_ACCESS_TOKEN}`, that's a problem since it will create an object where you just want a plain string. Remove the braces if they're actually in your code

Comment: I was able to find out some more info. Contrary to what I originally thought, it was indeed a CORS problem. Also, don't worry, I have my actual access token in place of {MY_ACCESS_TOKEN}.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was going on:

The Square APIs are designed to be hit from backend code (i.e. the server), and not from front end code (i.e. Vue components). To solve the issue, I had to add a simple Express js backend to my app.

I followed [a tutorial I found on Code Miner](https://blog.codeminer42.com/making-a-full-stack-app-with-vue-vite-and-express-that-supports-hot-reload/) to add the backend to my app. After that, I moved the code above from the `mounted()` method to an express router like so:

```
import express from "express";
import { Client, Environment } from "square";

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/menu", async (_req, res) => {
  const client = new Client({
    accessToken: ACCESS_TOKEN,  // In "real" code, you would use your actual token.
    environment: Environment.Sandbox
  });

  try {
    const response = await client.catalogApi.listCatalog();
    console.log(response.result.objects);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  // Add code below to do stuff with the catalog...
});
```

That allowed me to successfully get my catalog info using the Square API.